# How to connect flat and tilted edges properly?

Tags: mesh, objects, edges, topology, shadows

I create a mesh with this specific pattern and I need to connect this two edges without causing shading issue (img 1). If I just fill them with F key the shading doesn't work properly because the filled face isn't flat (img 2). The other option is to use a triangle but it may cause problems in the future (img 3). Is there any way to fill this gap smoothly with quads? [image] [image][image]

Comment: If you  right click and Shade Flat it should work, if you just want to shade flat these faces, select it and Ctrl F > Shade Flat

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I don't want to shade flat the faces. I just wonder how to connect them with flat quads..

Comment: You say that you don't want to shade flat but the rest of your mesh is shaded flat

Comment: Yea, I just showed the example but I forgot to mention that the transition has to be smoothed and beveled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the *Auto Smooth* option, it will only smooth between the faces that have the angle that you determine, increase the angle value until you're good, don't push too much otherwise it will smooth between the faces that are perpendicular and give bad result:

[image]

To keep some edges unaffected by the smoothing, select these edges and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Mark Sharp*:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to adjust auto smooth angle for individual faces but not for the entire object?

Comment: Ctrl E >Mark Sharp?